Mean variance optimization in R with minimum count and max weight constraint
I need to run a mean variance optimization in R using 50+ stocks, with minimum (and maximum) output count and max weight constraints. I am having trouble with Amat and bvec configurations for the same using solve.QP. Option to other solvers as well.
library(data.table); library(lubridate); library(dplyr); library(quadprog); options(scipen = 999)

# Create dummy data for 52 tickers and 3 years of weekly returns
stocks = data.table(Id=LETTERS[seq(from = 1, to = 26)])
stocks = rbind(stocks , data.table(Id=paste(stocks$Id, stocks$Id, sep="")), use.names=TRUE)
stocks = cross_join(stocks , data.table(Date=seq(ymd('2021-03-05'),ymd('2024-03-08'),by='weeks')))
set.seed(123); stocks[,Ret:=random_decimals <- runif(nrow(stocks), min = -.09, max = .05)]
print(stocks)

xtsPrc = as.xts.data.table(data.table::dcast(stocks,Date~Id,value.var=c("Ret")))
r = matrix(colMeans(xtsPrc),nrow=1)
C = cov(xtsPrc)
n = length(r)
maxwt = .03
Amat = cbind(1,diag(n))
bvec=c(1,rep(0,n))

Amat = cbind(Amat,-diag(n))
bvec = c(bvec,rep(-maxwt,n))
sol = solve.QP(Dmat=C,dvec=r,Amat=Amat,bvec=bvec,meq=1)
ans = data.table(Id=colnames(xtsPrc),Weight=sol$solution)[abs(Weight)>.00001,]; print(ans)

The problem is I am unable to input a minimum or maximum count constraint, and the optimizer is leaning towards an equal weighted solution given my strict max weight constraint. If you increase max weight to 5%, it will automatically start selection lower number of stocks. Is there a way to specify a min and max output count (say 25 - 40 stocks) with a max weight of 5%? Thank you

Search for R portfolio optimization with cardinality constraints

You need an MIQP (Mixed-Integer Quadratic Programming) solver for this.
